# How to insert json data into table with their corresponding columns in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to insert JSON data into the table with its corresponding key-values in SQLAlchemy in python. Below is my SQLAlchemy Table:

**MODEL**

```
db_string ="postgres://user:pwd@10.**.**.***:####/db_table"
db = create_engine(db_string) 

class Layout(Base):
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "col"} 
    __tablename__ = "layout"    #mention table name
    name = Column(String(1000), unique=True, primary_key = True)
    columndata = Column(String(10000), nullable=False)
    gridname = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    ownername = Column(String, nullable=False)
    createdat = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=(datetime.datetime.now()))
    modifiedat = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

I have a JSON data and also have an API in which I want to insert that JSON data (coming from UI) into my database' table.

**JSON**

```
{
  "layout": "layout-1",
  "columndata": {
        "colId": "#",
        "hide": false,
        "aggFunc": null,
      },
  },
  "gridname": "RT",
  "ownername": "user_1",
}
```

Here is the tricky part. That JSON data have all the column's value as above table requires except "createdat" & "modifieddat". I want to add that column value at insert time with current TIMESTAMP values. How could I do that?
NOTE: *In below API, data variable has my JSON.*

**API**

```
class LayoutSave(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):            
        db = create_engine(db_string)
        Session = sessionmaker(db)
        session = Session()
        Base.metadata.create_all(db)

        r = self.request.body     
        data = r.decode('utf8').replace("'",'"')

        # data variable has my JSON 

        session.add(Layout(**data))
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

Comment: what error do you get? It seems like `data` is still a string type & you haven't actually converted it to json or dictionary.

Comment: @HaleemurAli. I have just checked, u are right. Can you please tell me the answer accordingly changes u suggest, if you know.